# Mongoose Query with Dynamic Key that also contains the "and" operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

So I'm trying to query my MongoDB database using mongoose to fetch documents that have ****a specific family *AND* a specific analysis ID**** at the same time. Here is an example of the document structure:

```
_id: ObjectId("62b2fb397fda9ba6fe24aa5c")
day: 1
family: "AUTOMOTIVE"
prediction: -233.99999999999892
analysis: ObjectId("629c86fc67cfee013c5bf147")
```

The problem I face in this case is that **the name of the key of the *family* field is set dynamically** and could therefore have any other name such as "**product_family**", "**category**", etc. This is why, in order to fetch documents with a **dynamic key name**, I have to use the **where()** and **equals()** operators like so:

```
// Get the key of the field that is set dyncamically.
let dynamicKey = req.body.dynamicKey;

// Perform a query using a dynamic key.
documents = await Model.find().where(dynamicKey).equals(req.body.value);
```

HOWEVER, my goal here is **NOT** to just fetch all the documents with the dynamic key, but rather to **fetch the documents that have BOTH the dynamic key name AND ALSO a specific analysis Id**.

Had the family field NOT been dynamic, I could have simply used a query like so:

```
documents = await Model.find({ 
   $and: [{analysis: req.body.analysis_id}, {family: req.body.value}] 
});
```

but this does not seem possible in this case since **the keys inside the find() operator are mere text strings and not variables**. I also tried using the following queries with no luck:

```
documents = await Model.find().where(dynamicKey).equals(req.body.value).where('analysis').equals(req.body.analysis_id);

documents = await Model.find().where(dynamicKey).equals(req.body.value).where('analysis').equals(req.body.analysis_id);
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Is `dynamicKey` completely unknown,,,,,,,,,,,, or is it just something that possibly changes , but known, from query to query?  Queries can be constructed in any way you want before sending it to the MongoDB server.

Comment: @rickhg12hs the `dynamicKey` value is known but changes from query to query.

Comment: I'm a javascript novice, but can't you do something like, `documents = await Model.find({[dynamicKey]: req.body.value, analysis: req.body.analysis_id})`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs while you seem to be right about using `[dynamicKey]: req.body.value`, for some reason the query you suggested still returns all the documents that match only the analysis id, ignoring the value of the dynamic field.

Comment: What happens if your first, `findFilter = {[dynamicKey]: req.body.value, analysis: req.body.analysis_id}` and then `Model.find(findFilter)` ... or something like that.  I don't know `mongoose`, but I'm wondering if it is casting your filter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution, I posted a complete answer with 2 alternative solutions, including an extra required step. It works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rickhg12hs mentioned in the comments, part of the answer is to use the [] brackets to specify your dynamic key like so:

`await Model.find({[dynamicKey]: req.body.value, analysis: req.body.analysis_id});`

I also found out that another query that can work is this:

`await Model.find({analysis:req.body.analysis_id}).where(dynamicKey).equals(req.body.value);`

However, it seems that for either of these solutions to work **you also need to set your schema's strict mode to "false"**, since we are working with a dynamic key value.

Example:

```
var predictionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    day: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    prediction: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    analysis: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Analysis', // Reference the Analysis Schema
        required: true
    }
}, { strict: false });
```